# Best way to audit the updated fields using spring and hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc

I want to audit only modified fields in to db using spring 4 and hibernate.
I have a list action like add xxx and when ever user will call this action based on the create/update and delete.

I want to audit the field in db like one record in primary table which contains the selected action like add xxx and child table contains the all fields.
**I want only modified fields for update action.**
I gone through the list blogs for the same but didn't get any proper solution as per requirement.

**Can anyone suggest any best approch?**

Comment: [Hibernate Envers](https://docs.jboss.org/envers/docs/) would seem to do what you want.

Comment: http://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/spring-framework/spring-data-jpa-tutorial-auditing-part-one/ Is this what you are looking for ?

Comment: @Boris the Spider I have already checked the Envers but using hibernate Envers I can't add my custom entity like my action (add xxx) and other fields.